# Topology on the space of real valued bounded functions

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

First I was trying to prove that  the space of real valued bounded functions
\begin{align*}
   E=\{f \,\,| \,\,\,\,|f(x)| \leq k \,\,\,\, \forall x \in \mathbb{R}\} 
\end{align*}
can have two different topologies. I can find an example with two different  norms on $E$ such that the normed space can be either complete or incomplete. However i dont know if this difference of being complete or not implies that the resulting topological spaces will be different.

Comment: As the answer given below says, having two essentially different norms does not provide with different topologies. But if you need different topologies, use the following: First, the usual norm topology, given by the $\ell^\infty$-norm. Second, the topology of pointwise convergence, that is, the topology induced on $E$ by the product topology on $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$.

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not. In $\Bbb R$, if you consider the usual distance, then it is complete. But if you use the distance $d$ defined by $d(x,y)=|e^x-e^y|$, then it is not. However, both metrics induce the same topology.